# jQuery UI Sortable: possible to sort on <button> sub-elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a table which I succeeded in making sortable with the Sortable JQueryUI functionality.

My question is : is there a way to sort the elements of this table by clicking and holding sub-elements (in my case, buttons in the lines of the table) ?

Thanks in advance for your answers !

Comment: Can you show your current code?

Comment: You can surely, could you set up a jsfiddle for us to help u?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With span, div, td, and other elements works fine.

On buttons y default is not possible because the [`cancel`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-cancel) option is set to `input,textarea,button,select,option` so the button will not handle the sortable.

Ref:

> Prevents sorting if you start on elements matching the selector.

You can set it to empty string, or set a string without button and it will work

Code:

```
$("#languages tbody").sortable({
    cancel: ''
}).disableSelection();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/9XDVM/

Comment: OK, I didn't express myself very well, but your answer helped me. I should have specified « is there a way to sort the elements of this table by clicking and holding **only certain** sub-elements ». In my case the `cancel` selector is : `'td:not(.clickable-zone)'`.

Comment: @Pierre-YvesLeDévéhat glad to help you; I changed a bit title, if you want you can change it too or add more code